# Is it possible to view the call stack in the delphi 7 debugger?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-7

From what I can see there's no menu options to view a call-stack like I'm used to seeing in debuggers for other languages. Is this a feature that simply didn't exist in this (old) version of Delphi? Is there another way I can search for references or detect what other code within the project uses a particular function if viewing a call-stack in the debugger isn't possible?

Comment: All versions of Delphi that I can recall (I used Delphi 1) had a call stack view in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks! I must have overlooked the menu option since I didn't know what menu it was under.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from delphi 7

check this
[image]

and  the call stack
[image]

Answer (score 12):

If it's Delphi 7, start debugging your application and then use the View/Debug Windows/Call stack menu.